# Arquivos duplicados no AppManifest.xml.

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou tentando subir uma atualização do meu app, e esta surgindo o erro 2001: Há arquivos duplicados no AppManifest.xml.

Como solucionar? Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206735%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) informa que você precisa fazer o *build* da aplicação novamente e, caso isso não resolva, deve acessao o *AppManifest.xaml* manualmente e procurar pela duplicação.

OBS: o link é sobre erro de apliação windows, mas, pelo que vi desenvolvendo até agora, mensagens iguais referem-se mesmo a problemas iguais das plataformas.

OBS2: se você usa algum controle de versão (ex: Git), pode ver o histórico de alterações do *AppManifest.xaml*, assim será fácil identificar quando algo foi inserido lá e, consequentemente, achar a duplicação.